# how to determine the count of the array and output a single value

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a c++ program for the following problem: Suppose we flew an airplane from Europe to North America and while measuring our height above the sea level (> 0) every x kilometers. we measured zero where there was sea and greater than 0 where there was land. How can we define the two sea sides of the ocean and count the number of islands between europe and north america. so far i am able to write the following code but i am unable to find the count of the islands.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many measurements?" << endl;
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int heights[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cin >> heights[i];
    }
    int E, A;
    E=1;
    while (heights[E]>0) {
        E++;
    }
    A=N-2;
    while (heights[A]>0) {
        A--;
    }

    cout << E+1 << " " << A+1 << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question about a programming language?

Comment: What do those `while` loops accomplish?

Comment: Geography problem is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to find how many contiguous sections of positive numbers there are in your array?

```
// put your measurements here, or code to load from file etc.
std::vector<int> measurements {0,1,5,2,0,0,0,1,3,4,2,1,2,1,0,0};

int islands = 0;
bool prev = false;
for (int m : measurements) {
  bool curr = (m > 0);
  if (curr && !prev)
    islands++;
  prev = curr;
}
std::cout << ("Islands: " + std::to_string(islands) + "\n");
```

That will add one to `islands` each time a positive element appears after a zero (or at the start), so when you're done, `islands` will be the number of contiguous positive measurements.

Comment: I assume that the first measurement is `>0` unless the plane starts from sea :-)

Comment: I was assuming the land at the beginning and end would be stripped out; indeed, if those are included, my code will give an answer 2 higher than the number of "islands" as it'll count the starting and ending landmasses as "islands".

Comment: yes exactly, i want to find out the positive numbers in the array and excluding the two land masses of the continents.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with the following code:

```
int islands = 0;
int land = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if(land == -1 && heights[i] == 0)
        land = 0;
    else if(land == 0 && heights[i] > 0)
        land = 1;
    else if(land == 1 && heights[i] == 0) {
        land = 0;
        islands++;
    }
}
```

The variable `land` tracks whether you are over land or water; when it changes from land (1) to water (0) we add another island.

The initial `-1` is necessary so we don't count the initial landmass (a continent) as an island.

Comment: upvoting for getting basically the same solution at the same time as me :)

Comment: one more question what should i write in the cout statement

Comment: `cout << "There are " << islands << " islands.\n";` should do the trick.

Comment: i tried to use the code but upon running it tells 0 islands no matter what values I give as input

Comment: sorry, my bad. I forgot a `{` for the for loop. Edited post. I have compiled and tested the code now, it works for me.

Comment: @ArunRajGandhi I just ran the code from your edit: How many measurements?
10
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
0
1
There are 2 islands.

Comment: thank you very much sir!!!, can this code me modified so that we can count two consecutive islands , such that if i input 012, 0 is sea and 1 is first island and 2 is another island

Comment: So the islands would be adjacent to each other? What makes them islands then? You could, of course simply count the number of positive measurements, but I doubt that is what you want.